# CanPlace tag doesn't work

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am building an Adventure map in gamemode 2, so you can't place Blocks and I want to set a Item / Block in a slot and get a Block which is placeable in gamemode 2:

```
/replaceitem entity @p slot.inventory.0 quartz_block 1 0 {CanPlace:true}
```

It doesn't work with this command, please help.

Answer (score 3):

`CanPlace` is not a data tag that exists, nor is it a boolean. You are probably looking for the `CanPlaceOn` tag, which does exist, but is still not a boolean.

Here's a helpful wiki page on data tags:
https://minecraft.wiki/w/Player.dat_format

`CanPlaceOn` is a list of strings, each string containing the name of a block that it can be placed on. For example, to get a quartz block that can be placed on stone and dirt:

```
/replaceitem entity @p slot.hotbar.0 quartz_block 1 0 {CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:stone","minecraft:dirt"]}
```

Answer (score -1):

If your using Pocket Edition, try this

`/replaceitem entity @p slot.hotbar 0 quartz_block 1 0 {"minecraft:can_place_on":{"blocks":["stone","dirt"]}}`

Comment: The OP is not, looking at the tags used in his post.